# nativescript global http header

Tags: nativescript

Is there a way to set global header to http module with Nativescript ?

Instead doing this :

```
const http = require('http')

return http.request({
        url : ...,
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
           'Authorization' : 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c',
           'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
});
```

I would like to have something like this:

```
const http = require('http')

http.headers = {
       'Authorization' : 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c',
       'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

return http.request({
        url : ...,
        method: 'GET'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a global function for common http headers like

```
function getCommonHeaders() {
  return {
     "Content-Type": "application/json",
     "Authorization": "Bearer " + config.token
  }
}
```

And then use them in all HTTP requests

```
const http = require('http');

return http.request({
    url : ...,
    method: 'GET',
    headers: getCommonHeaders()
});
```

You may also want to consider storing your key/token in a configuration setting or in `application-settings`.

Comment: I know, but i would have a better way to do that like axios : 

`const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://some-domain.com/api/',
  timeout: 1000,
  headers: {'X-Custom-Header': 'foobar'}
});`